# Wickr Me doesn't launch on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, kernel

Installed Wickr Me via the regular software center (so, as a snap). It's the latest version as listed on their website (5.77.12). After installing it, when clicking on the app, it doesn't launch. It doesn't show up as an active process in the system monitor, and there aren't any error messages either. Rebooting Ubuntu doesn't help.

Details of my Ubuntu installation below. Anyone else experience this? Any fix? I've contacted Wickr support but they don't respond.

```
-Version-
Kernel : Linux 5.8.0-50-generic (x86_64)
Version : #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021
C Library : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31
Distribution : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: Old thread, but I had this same problem. I tried opening through the terminal to see what it would say, and it gave me a "no protocol specified." I think it had something to do with it not being able to access the Xwindows gui... or something. so in the terminal I gave it a "xhost +" command. Then I ran it through the terminal (not as su) and it opened up just fine. So I got it to work, but I guess being a Linux non-expert, I wouldn't know how to get this to work without the same process every time. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They updated the snap packages and it seems Wickr Me does not run on Ubuntu 20.04 anymore. Last time switching back to beta channel did work, because the actual version on beta channel was 5.47.25. It seems that was the last version  which worked with Ubuntu 20.04.

But now the beta channel got updated to version 5.76.13 which does not run on Ubuntu 20.04. So changing the release channel does not help anymore and currently all version which are installable via snap do not run on this distribution.

If you try to run wickrme from terminal it gives error message: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Comment: Yes, I also tried installing the current beta without success. Is there any way to get one's hands on 5.47.25 or earlier to your knowledge?

Comment: I've had some feedback from Wickr now. It seems that the issue occurs only on older machines, or at least that's what seems to be the case in their replication efforts. It's certainly true that my machine is rather old. Yours?

Comment: Thank you for the details. Yes, my machine is really old too. Is it related perhaps to some hardware driver? Or do they want to use some techonolgy what old hardware does not support?

Comment: I have several fairly similar age and configuration 20.04 LTS machines.  Two run wickrme, one doesn't.  All are at version 5.82.14 rev 543.  I've tried removing/installing wickr on the failing machine to no avail.  syslog indicates that it launched but the GUI never displays.

Comment: I have a Lenovo T14 second gen, so relatively recently hardware running 21.10. Currently no versions of Wickr are able to run on my system, I've tried switching the channels, and also tried the different versions (default, pro, and enterprise) but all return the same `No protocol specified IOT instruction (core dumped)` error.

Answer (score 1):

From wickr support: If you are having trouble opening Wickr on your Linux device, please check your processor for AVX and AVX2 support by opening a Terminal window and typing in:

```
grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | cut -f 2 -d: | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | grep avx
```

This should list both if you have AVX and AVX2 support on this processor.

Alternatively, you can find your model name and number by typing in a Terminal:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

After getting your CPU model information from the command above, you can enter that model name and number into Intel's website to check compatibility. Under the Advanced Technologies tab, look for Instruction Set Extensions.

If you do not have AVX and AVX2 support listed here, you will need to uninstall the current Wickr version and install the candidate version instead, until we are able to resolve this issue.

You will need to type the following in the Terminal to install the candidate version of Wickr Me. To change the app installed, change the final command to "wickrpro" or "wickrenterprise"

```
sudo snap install --channel=candidate wickrme
```